# Stackdriver Debugger on Google Compute Engine

Tags: node.js, stackdriver, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to transition to Stackdriver Debugger because of the [announcement](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/09/announcing-Stackdriver-Debugger-for-Node.js.html) the other day of their Node JS beta component now publicly available...  I'm on compute engine so I found this [part](https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs/setup/nodejs#compute_engine) of the documentation...  I added the cloud_debugger scope to my instance with:

```
gcloud compute instances set-service-account <INSTANCE> --scopes="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud_debugger"
```

and of course the vm had access to all of the Google API's checked off with the initial creation so the cloud-platform scope is there...

I then run this npm from the shell:

```
sudo npm install --save @google-cloud/debug-agent
```

(it needed sudo for some reason), I then include the:

```
require('@google-cloud/debug-agent').start({ allowExpressions: true });
```

at the top of my node files but when I load [console.cloud.google.com/debug](http://console.cloud.google.com/debug) ... I'm not seeing any of my code... I've tried a few other things since, such as selecting a Cloud Source Repository... I do see my code finally but the right hand side is telling me my code is not deployed... I'm not wanting to use stackdriver debugger with a publicly deployed project just yet, perhaps sometime in the future after the API has been more fully developed, but I'd still need access to the full GUI suite.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the screenshot you provided, it seems like you were hit by the bug being fixed here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-debug-nodejs/pull/334. We'll try to get this into a release soon.

Sorry about the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Please enable the stackdriver debugger API for your project. (assuming it's off)
https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/clouddebugger.googleapis.com/?q=debugger

Comment: API is enabled... appears to be on but of course not working as a debugger

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwA2KVlVFTQtZHotZ3dYWWluN0U

Comment: I've now got the right hand column, but there appears to be a bug (I did have the right hand column before taking the first screenshot)...  Will comment again if I can't assign a proper snapshot because of some other bug

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwA2KVlVFTQtczhaQmQxNFByRkE